# How to convert this code into Blade/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am using this code:

```
<input type="text" name="search" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['search'])){echo 
        $_GET['search']; } ?>" placeholder="Search by name...">
```

I want to change this code into Blade/PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by -

```
<input
    type="text"
    name="search"
    value="{{ isset($_GET['search'] ? $_GET['search'] : '') }}"
    placeholder="Search by name...">
```

Comment: This code has an XSS vulnerability. This means I can send you a specially crafted link to this app, and if you view it, it runs JavaScript on your browser. If you are logged into the app, it means I can steal your cookies and have a reasonable chance of impersonating you.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
<input type="text" name="search" value="{{request()->search}}" placeholder="Search by name...">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<input type="text" name="search" value="{{ request('search') }}" placeholder="Search by name...">
```